# Smooth move picture box as button click: picturebox keep moving

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to code the picturebox1 to move as I click button1 it is indeed work but problem is that the picturebox1 keep moving without stop even I already put condition for it to stop but if I put `PictureBox1.Left + 1` it will stop the exact point I want but I want it faster so I need it to be `PictureBox1.Left + 5`

here is the code I write:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Left + 5, PictureBox1.Top + 0)
    If PictureBox1.Left = 343 Then
        Timer1.Stop()

    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
```

Timer1 interval is 1 Enable = false

Comment: oh i found the problem because when +5 it won't equal 343 ... so I need sth that can divide by 5. what a math !

Comment: post your answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

343 is not multiple of 5, so the value will never be equal. You should test for `.left >343`

To have a smoother animation I suggest to increment by 1 and reduce the timer interval time